# How create ghost images and copy to many drives

Tags: hard-drive, copy, image, disk-image

I am looking for the cleanest and most reliable solution to create ghost images of a windows 7 based machine and copy these images to multiple hard drives.

I am looking for the software needed to create the image and hopefully some instructions on how to accomplish this succesfully.

I am also looking for recommendations on hardware to copy multiple drives quickly and reliably. I will potentially

Comment: Product and service recommendations are off-topic per the [FAQ](http://serverfault.com/faq). Unfortunately, "best method, give me reccs," questions are spam magnets and are rather subjective.

Answer (score 1):

The best solution for you will be Clonezilla and Clonezilla Server http://clonezilla.org/. 
I used to recover over 200(every with 2 drives) machines in only 2h (server with 3 drives in RAID 0, 1GB network with 10GB FC core (5 rooms with 20 PCs) ).

For server I will recommend something with raid 0(on 2 or more drives) but clonezilla is using multicast so all you need is decent pentium IV with good network and big disk for images.

With some work you can use WOL and Clonezilla and sit in char while all work is dooing itsefl.

There are many tutorials on network about setting up clonezilla server.

Comment: +1, Clonezilla is excellent.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to spend money on software, check out ShadowProtect: http://storagecraft.com.au/

I use ShadowProtect IT Edition which is around $2000 AUD for a 1 year licence.

It is reliable and in the times that it does not work, there is a support team you can rattle your questions to.

The bare metal restore is great and it works all the time I have used it so far, *fingers crossed (^_^)*

That being said, there are a few free options available but I have not tested any.
I have tried Acronis about 4 years ago, and I find ShadowProtect is great.